# How do I pass an array in a swift json request

Tags: php, json, swift

How can I pass an array to my Php backend using swift. Do i have to for loop each value and append it to the request body?

Here is my code

```
        let url = URL(string: "url.com/page")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        let id = user?["id"] as! String
        let party = partyName.text!

        let body = "id=\(id)&party_name=\(party)&party_invited=\(usersInvited)" 

        //********--usersInvited-- is the array i want to pass



        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if error == nil{

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                        guard let parseJSON = json else{
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }


                       print(parseJSON["status"])

                    } catch{

                        print("Caught an error: \(error)")
                    }


                } else{
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }

            })
        }).resume()
```

But that code sends the array as one whole string with an output like this: ["57", "60"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, but it looks like you want to JSON encode your array, but as a URL parameter?

(I've assumed that `usersInvited` is an array of strings)

You could go via JSONSerialisation?

```
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: usersInvited, options: [])
let string = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)!

let body = "id=\(id)&party_name=\(party)&party_invited=\(string)"
```

Or if that's not *quite* what you want (you've got a space after the comma in your question), you could just do it by hand?

```
let string = "[" + usersInvited.map { "\"\($0)\"" }.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
```

My vote would be to use option 1 and make your server accept what it outputs.

---

If you mean you want it to look like `party_invited=1,2,3,4` then you could use joined to convert the array like this

```
let string = usersInvited.joined(separator: ",")

let body = "id=\(id)&party_name=\(party)&party_invited=\(string)"
```

---

If you mean you want this `party_invited=1&party_invited=2&party_invited=3` then you can use map and joined

```
let string = usersInvited.map { "party_invited=\($0)" }.joined(separator: "&")

let body = "id=\(id)&party_name=\(party)&\(string)"
```

Comment: I ended up using your 3rd idea where I sent party_invited separated by commas like party_invited = 1,2,3,4 and then split them up and put them in an array in Php. Works great ty